# Centered content when resizing the browser is going off to the right side of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a random quote generator: http://codepen.io/Kestvir/pen/peqjZZ , 
and while doing the html/css part of things, I've encountered a problem with the content, that is inside the transparent background. When resizing the window, the content is going off to right side, and it no longer looks like it is centered, when it actually is. If I remove the margins of the background (`margin:  0 150px;`) then this problem no longer exists, but then the transparent background becomes as wide as the entire window. I suspect that this is because my `<div class="quote-bckgr">` is outside of the container, but I did so, because I had no idea, how to center my contents with the mentioned div class being inside the container, as opposed, of how it is now, because it was stuck to the very top of the page. How should I fix the text and buttons going off to the right, and not looking centered ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/audetcameron/pen/vxvrEr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted. I added the margin inside container and row divs, added the background color and border radius and removed it from your other class.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/audetcameron/pen/vxvrEr)

```
    <body>
      <div class="quote-bckgr">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="new-margin">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1> Welcome to CIV5 random quote generator!</h1>
                <div id="quotation"></div>
                <div id="author"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class= "col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
                  <a href="#" id="twitter" class="btn" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>Tweet This Quote</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <a href="#" id="newQuote" class="btn" target="_blank">New Quote</a>
                </div>          
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

and css

```
.quote-bckgr {
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      transform: translatey(-50%);
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .new-margin{
      margin:0 155px;
      background-color: rgba(25, 0, 0, .45);
      border-radius:5px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I wanted. I just have one more question now concerning the rows. I know that you can nest them, but is the nesting needed in my case ? I wanted to close the first row after  <div class="col-sm-12">, but couldn't, because of the <div class="new-margin">. Or maybe the nesting of the second row inside the first one is needed and is correct and I shouldn't change the code when it comes to rows here ?

Comment: I suppose you don't have to nest the rows as long as you put the .new-margin outside of the rows themselves like here http://codepen.io/audetcameron/pen/oZJPdW